# SPA validate laravel sanctum when refresh browser

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I'm using vuejs and sanctum to authenticate my spa. Everything works but the confusing part for me is how do we verify if we're login or not when we **REFRESH** vuejs?

for sanctum I'm using sessions based so there's no token. The only thing we have is '**laravel_session**' cookie.

Answer (score 0):

Add api endpoint for getting data auth user, everytime user refresh the page, you need to request auth user,

If the response 401 mean the user is not authenticated and you can redirect user to the login page or something,

You can use `beforeEach` from Vue router for checking the auth user before the page loaded

But if you do this, the app will request everytime user refresh or change page, so basically what i do is,

- Make a auth store with pinia/vuex
- Store the auth user data from api to the pinia/vuex
- in `beforeEach` router check if there a data in auth store
- if there no data, request again to the api and if the response is 401 that mean user is not login